# What does member[H|T] mean?

Tags: prolog

I am just learning Prolog and stumbled across following question: [Prolog - Seeing if the same element occurs in two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729326/prolog-seeing-if-the-same-element-occurs-in-two-lists).

This question includes following line: `=(member(X,[H|T]), member[Z|Q]))`.

I know about [member(?Elem, ?List)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2), but I do not understand the `member[Z|Q]` part. What does this mean? And isn't there a closing paranthesis too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary:

> Do not worry about this *at all*.

Here are several reasons:

## Syntax error

First of all, this is **invalid syntax**. When you consult the program you link to, you get:

```
ERROR: file.pl:5:28: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

indicating exactly the line containing:

```
    =(member(X,[H|T]), member[Z|Q])),
```

## Dubious meaning

Second, even if we somehow fix the problematic syntax, and write this line for example as:

```
    =(member(X,[H|T]), member_whatever),
```

Then it would still be **highly dubious** that this is what the author *meant* to express.

The predicate that is used in this case is `(=)/2`, and you can write this *equivalently* using **infix notation** as:

```
    member(X,[H|T]) = member_whatever,
```

And from this, it is already clear that this **cannot succeed** because `(=)/2` does not even hold for the **much more general case**

```
    member(_,_) = member_whatever,
```

So, it definitely fails of course also in the more specific case above!

## Fundamental issues

When programming in Prolog, focus on a *clear description* of **what holds**.

For example, to state that "the same elements occurs in two lists" is straight-forward:

```
element_in_both(E, As, Bs) :-
     member(E, As),
     member(E, Bs).
```

**That's it!** You can read it as follows: **If** `E` is a member of `As` *and* `E` is a member of `Bs` **then** `E` is a member of *both* `As` and `Bs`.

It works quite generally, for example:

```
?- length(Cs, _),
   append(As, Bs, Cs),
   element_in_both(E, As, Bs).
Cs = [E, E],
As = Bs, Bs = [E] ;
Cs = [E, E, _2946],
As = [E],
Bs = [E, _2946] ;
Cs = [E, _2940, E],
As = [E],
Bs = [_2940, E] .
```

You can use this predicate to **generate** lists where this relation **holds**, to **test** *whether* it holds for a specific instance, to **complete** partial lists *such that* they satisfy this predicate etc.

All of this follows from a clear declarative description of the *conditions* that make this relation *hold*.

In Prolog courses, there is a tendency to needlessly complicate this rather simple fundamental principle of declarative programming. Do not fall into this trap. If your predicate becomes convoluted, your are often overlooking something simpler.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the long and detailed explaination on a syntax error! Still learned something new (the `You can use this predicate to generate lists where this relation holds` part)

Comment: Yes, that's one of the major attractions of logic programming: From a pure declarative description, you can **generate** cases that satisfy the relation. This is nice for writing test cases, and also to simply study the predicate: If you want to find out what a predicate means, try the most general query (where all arguments are variables) and thus ask Prolog for *any* answers! This is very convenient to find out more about predicates, and also very useful in practice because it makes your code very versatile and compact.